# crawl site and retrieve only links that start with http://

Tags: php

I am using the following code to retrieve links from the `<a>` tag but would like to make some adjustments.

1. Would like to only return links that begin with "http://"
2. Would like to include links to image and script references that include "http://"

**Would be even better if it can return links for all tags as long as it begins with "http://"**

Here is the current code:

```
<?php

$html = file_get_contents('http://mattressandmore.com/in-the-community/');

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

// grab all the links on the page
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$hrefs = $xpath->evaluate("/html/body//a");

for ($i = 0; $i < $hrefs->length; $i++) {
       $href = $hrefs->item($i);
       $url = $href->getAttribute('href');
       echo $url.'<br />';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to apply `starts-with` function to `href` attribute of `a` element :)
Check some reference and you will get idea, here is the code:

```
...
$hrefs = $xpath->evaluate("/html/body//a[starts-with(@href, \"http:\")]");
...
```

Full code:

```
<?php

$html = file_get_contents('http://mattressandmore.com/in-the-community/');

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

// grab all the links on the page
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$hrefs = $xpath->evaluate("/html/body//a[starts-with(@href, \"http:\")]");

for ($i = 0; $i < $hrefs->length; $i++) {
       $href = $hrefs->item($i);
       $url = $href->getAttribute('href');
       echo $url.'<br />';
}
?>
```

Similarly you can try for `img` tag with `src` starting with "http://" and `script` `href` attribute too.

```
...
$hrefs = $xpath->evaluate("/html/body//img[starts-with(@src, \"http:\")]");
...
```